# Generics, passing wrong types?

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference between the last two statements ? why does one statement work and the other doesn't ?

```
package Main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void printIt(List<Object> l)
    {
        System.out.println(l);
    } 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l =new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("A");

        //what is the differance between the following statments ? 

        printIt(Arrays.asList("A")); // it compiles successfully
        printIt(l); // it does not compile

    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Comment: List<String> l=new ArrayList<>(); does not compile anyway because the ArrayList has no Type declared.

Comment: @Jankapunkt It does compile, this is the diamond operator introduced in Java 7.

Comment: `List<String>` is not assignable to `List<Object>`, e.g. if you have `List<Object>` you can add e.g. value 3 which doesn't make sense for list of strings

Comment: @csharpfolk : according to what you have just said both statement should not compile !!

Comment: @Nour.kotmawi why, compiler can use target type to infer type of `Arrays.asList("A")` expression just like in `List<Object> x = Arrays.asList("A")`

Comment: @Nour.kotmawi call `printIt(Arrays.asList("A"));` defaults to `printIt(Arrays.<Object>asList("A"));` not to `printIt(Arrays.<String>asList("A"));`

Answer (score 4):

The problem is `printIt()` method expects `List<Object>` as parameter but we are passing `List<String>` to it, that's why there is compilation problem. 
Replace the parameter List in method printIt() as below:

```
    public static void printIt(List<? extends Object> l)
    {
        System.out.println(l);
    }
```

Now both will compile,

Comment: @Nour, I am using Java-7, and on my machine, both lines are not compiling and giving the same compilation error, saying that : printIt() requires List<Object> and List<String> cannot be applied,

Comment: You get that because type inference was still a bit weak in Java 7. It has been improved in Java 8. You need to use `printIt(Arrays.<Object>asList("A"));` instead to work with Java 7.

Answer (score 3):

This is because your method expects a `List<Object>` and you give it a `List<String>`.

As weird as it can appear the first time you read this, a `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>`.

In your example, you don't modify the content of the lists but let's imagine a method where you want to add a new element.

```
public static void addIt(List<Object> l, Object o)
{
    l.add(o);
} 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> l =new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("A");
    addIt(l, new Integer(1)); // What?! you want to add an Integer to a List<String>!!!!
}
```

You will have to use wildcards [(`?`)](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-generics/wildcards.html) or to solve your problem so your your List .

```
public static void printIt(List<?> l) //or printIt(List<? extends Object> l)
{
    System.out.println(l);
}
```

The case of `printIt(Arrays.asList("A"))` is a bit different. It is due to the fact that the generic is determined dynamically, by [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) on a generic method.

```
List<Object> l = Arrays.asList("A"); //this is valid, the generic type is determined from the type we expect in this declaration.
```

Comment: this is obvious for me but also 
printIt(Arrays.asList("A"));   shouldn't compile !!

Comment: @Nour.kotmawi Sorry I had forgotten this part. I completed my answer

Answer (score 2):

To help you grok this, here is another *compiling* code example that demonstrated type inference from *return type*:

```
import java.util.*;

// our main class becomes a file but the main method is still found
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    foo(createList()); // T must be Object
  }

  private static void foo(List<Object> objs) { }

  private static <T> List<T> createList() { return new ArrayList<>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so as @csharpfolk mentioned it is all about "Type Inference"!
the following document could be helpful to understand the idea behind that!

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html